# React native webview "can't find variable"

Tags: webview

I'm making a function using webview in react-native project.

I want to use hello variable to alert when webview is loading,
but I get an error alert

> ReferenceError: Can't find variable: hello

I want to use hello variable, I don't want to use "alert("hello")" code;

How do I send hello variable to html??

Here is my code:

```
import React, { useEffect, useMemo, useState } from 'react';
import { WebView } from 'react-native-webview';

export const WebViewComponent: React.FC<any> = () => {
    const hello = 'hello';
    const code = ` 
        try {
            alert(${hello});
        } catch (e) {
            alert(e);
        }
    `;

    const html = `
        <!DOCTYPE html>
        <html lang="en">
            <head>
                <meta charset="UTF-8" />
                <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
            </head>
            <body>
                <h1>View</h1>
            </body>
        </html>
    `;

    return (
        <View 
            style={{ 
               backgroundColor: white,
               height: 600,
               borderRadius: 20 
            }}
        >
                    <WebView
                        javaScriptEnabled={true}
                        injectedJavaScript={code}
                        scrollEnabled={true}
                        bounces={false}
                        source={{ html }}
                    />
                </View>
    )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I want to use injectedJavaScript or injectJavaScript. This code is example.

Answer (score 0):

I solved by changing "${hello}" to ""${hello}"".